# Mega-straight flush with a huger hand

Tags: probability, combinatorics, card-games

Three days ago I asked about the [probability of drawing a *straight flush*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1287847/straight-flush-probability-with-a-huge-hand) when being dealt $26$ out of the $52$ cards of the deck, which [Michael](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/81790/michael) wisely solved.

Now I'd like to make things more complicated, I want to know the probability of drawing a ***Mega-straight flush***! I define a *Mega-straight flush* simply as $7$ cards of the same suit that are consecutive. But that wouldn't change much of the calculus. So there comes the twist. In this game, after being dealt the $26$ cards, if you have a *straight flush*, you are dealt $6$ more cards.

So given that, what's the Expected Value of ***Mega-straight flushes***? (I find it easier than calculating it's probability)

EDIT: *I'm aware the first problem wasn't* completely *solved, but Michael offered a way to solve it in polynomial time using a computer (I actually did it and took less than a tenth of a second), while apparently would require going through all the possible deals. That's the kind of solution I have in mind: Some insight into the problem that reduces the complex combinatorics it have into something that can be easely treated.*

Comment: Your first question was too hard, even with computer help.  It was not solved; Michael and I provided general guidance but no solution.  This question starts with a (nonexistent) solution to the first one, and builds more difficulty on top.  Why are you asking these questions?

Comment: @vadim123 I like thinking about hard combinatorial problems. I really considered the first problem solved. That is because it was a problem that was aparently unsolvable, even using computer, and Michael offered a way to solve it in polinomical time.

Comment: does this Q have a real-life application?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry Yes. I'm trying to calculate probabilities in bingo, but using cards makes the questioning clearer and easier to calculate. Then I apply further programming.